# Why using Napierian logarithm gives me the same result of doing properties?

Tags: logarithms

I wanted to change the base of this logarithm $\log_432$ from 4 to 2 so it could be easier to solve. Using some properties I get 2.5 as a result. However I was told that if I use $\frac{\ln 32}{\ln 4}$ I get the same result. Can someone explain me how this ln works?

Comment: It’s the [change of base formula](http://home.windstream.net/okrebs/page57.html) it is: $\log_b{x} = \frac{\log_a{x}}{\log_a{b}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general$$y:=\log_ax\implies b^{y\log_b a}=a^y=x\implies y\log_b a=\log_bx\implies y=\tfrac{\log_bx}{\log_ba},$$whether you use $b=2$ or $b=e$.

Comment: I can never answer fast enough to make it worth answering anything lol. The 0.001% of the questions I know the answer to... I’m too slow.

Answer (score 1):

$\log_432$ is the number $x$ such that $4^x=32$.

Taking the natural logarithm at both sides, we get

$$\ln(4^x)=x·\ln(4)=\ln(32)$$

Finally,
$$x=\frac{\ln(32)}{\ln(4)}$$